# How to annotate nodes and edges with Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

How can I draw a graph with Graphviz and annotate its nodes and edges?

For example:

```
(a: level=0) --3--> (b: level=1)  
(a: level=0) --2--> (c: level=1)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is quite simple, here's a `dot` file for your example (`test.dot`):

```
strict digraph {
    1 [label="a: level=0"];
    2 [label="b: level=1"];
    3 [label="c: level=1"];
    1 -> 2 [label="3"];
    1 -> 3 [label="2"];
}
```

which with `dot -Tpng -o test.png test.dot` will output:

[image: dot output]

There are way more parameters you can set to get the layout that you want. I suggest you look through the [Graphviz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language).